# href link not working on absolute background image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Trying to add a link over a background image of head-bg-image div into ul li.but the link is not working

```
<div id="product_banner">
<div class="head-bg">
<div class="head-bg-img"></div>

<ul class="d-inline-block " style="nav navbar navbar-left d-flex d-inline-flex" >
    <li class="nav-item d-inline-flex  align-items-center mr-2" style="margin- 
left:25px;color:#959c97;">
        <a>Home</a>
    </li> 
    <li class="nav-item d-inline-flex  align-items-center mr-2" style="margin-left:25px; 
    color:#959c97;">
        <h5>Service 2</h5>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

here is my css here. hover also not working

```
#product_banner .head-bg-img {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: url(http://demo.nrgthemes.com/projects/nrgnetwork/img/bg.jpg);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.2;
z-index: 1;
background-position: center center;
}

#product_banner .head-bg-content {
height: 400px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
z-index: 200;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 5000px;
}
```

here is the code for hover,it's also not working

```
 product_banner .head-bg-img a{
 color:#fcfffd;
 font-weight:bold;
 }
 #product_banner .head-bg-img a:hover{
 color:#fcfffd;font-weight:bold;
 }
```

Comment: `<div class="head-bg-img"></div>` is an empty element so your selector `product_banner .head-bg-img a` won't work unless you add some link as its child.

Comment: what should be the code now?

Comment: Its hard to tell anything unless we have some clear code structure. For example you have styles for an element with a class `.head-bg-content` but there is no such element in  markup.

Comment: You have quite a few problems with your code there. Do you want the background image covering the entire window?  Get rid of the `z-inexes`.  Your `ul style=` is a bunch of classes instead of inline css.  Put all of those classes inside the `class` attribute. You dont need `background-posiotion` or `background-size` since you have `height: 100%` and `width:100%` and you are setting the absolute position with `top` and `left`.  etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to work here:
What I did was remove the "z-index: 1;" from ".head-bg-img" because that will put the background **over** the content, making the links not work. For the hover code, don't forget the # in front of "product_banner .head-bg-img a". Also, you are selecting the "a" in "head-bg-img" when you really should be selecting the "a" in "nav-item" because the links are a child of the class nav-item, not of head-bg-img. Make sure to check the hierarchy of your HTML in order to reference the correct CSS selectors.

```css
#product_banner .head-bg-img {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: url(http://demo.nrgthemes.com/projects/nrgnetwork/img/bg.jpg);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-size: cover;
opacity: 0.2;
background-position: center center;
}

#product_banner .head-bg-content {
height: 400px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 5000px;
}
 #product_banner .nav-item a{
 color:#959c97;
 font-weight:bold;
 }
 #product_banner .nav-item a:hover{
 color:#fcfffd;font-weight:bold;
 }
```

```html
<div id="product_banner">
  <div class="head-bg">
  <div class="head-bg-img"></div>

  <ul class="d-inline-block head-bg-content" style="nav navbar navbar-left d-flex d-inline-flex" >
      <li class="nav-item d-inline-flex  align-items-center mr-2" style="margin- 
  left:25px;color:#959c97;">
          <a>Home</a>
      </li> 
      <li class="nav-item d-inline-flex  align-items-center mr-2" style="margin-left:25px; 
      color:#959c97;">
          <a>Service 2</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```